# NHibernate Query for a Sql Query

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

Let me explain my scenario. I have a table HSPartList which has partName, description, issueNo etc. When search is to made, I have a criteria which should list all the parts with latest issueNo. ie. If the table data is as follows:

```
|PartName| PartDesc| IssueNo|

TestPart1  TestPart1  1
TestPart1  TestPart1  2
TestPart2  TestPart2  1
TestPart2  TestPart2  2
```

In this example when I search for latest issues It should return only

```
|PartName| PartDesc| IssueNo|

TestPart1  TestPart1  2
TestPart2  TestPart2  2
```

I have sql query for that. I need to convert that to a nHibernate query.

Sql query is:

`select * from HS_PartList HS where HS.IsLive = 1 and HS.PartName Like '%test%' and IssueNo=(select max(issueNo) from  HS_PartList where HS_PartList.PartName=HS.PartName)`

NHibernate version is 2.1.2.4000

Comment: @ suja u need only TestPart2  TestPart2  2 ?

Comment: No, all the parts with latest issueNo

Comment: First get a list from the  HSPartList  with latest IssueNothen search for the PartName in that list

Comment: Can I have a single HQuery for it?

Comment: Have edited the post and changed the sql query

Answer (score 2):

```
var subquery = DetachedCriteria.For<Part>()
    .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("Name", "part.Name"))  <-- part is the alias of the main query
    .SetProjection(Projections.Max("IssueNo"));

var results = session.CreateCriteria<Part>("part")
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("IsLive", true))
    .Add(Restrictions.Like("Name", teststring, MatchMode.Anywhere))
    .Add(Subqueries.Eq("IssueNo", subquery))
    .List();
```

Comment: what 0? an Empty list? an integer? have you checked the generated sql?

Comment: My query is : 
var subquery = DetachedCriteria.For<HSPartList>()
    .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("PartName", "part.PartName"))  //<-- part is the alias of the main query
    .SetProjection(Projections.Max("IssueNo"));

                            var results = session.CreateCriteria<HSPartList>("part")
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("IsLive", true))
    .Add(Restrictions.Like("PartName", "%" + partName + "%", MatchMode.Anywhere))
    .Add(Subqueries.Eq("IssueNo", subquery))
    .List();

Comment: `"%" + partName + "%"` -> `partName`. And to test comment out `Add(Subqueries.Eq("IssueNo", subquery))` if the like and isLive return the correct results

Answer (score 2):

```
  Using Hql it Works fine 
string SearchTerm = "TestPart2";
string search = "and (partdetail.PartName like '%" + SearchTerm + "%') ";
var hql = string.Format(@"select partdetail  from HSPartList as partdetail  where  IssueNo =(select Max(IssueNo)  from HSPartList)") + search;
var context = _session.CreateQuery(hql).List<HSPartList>();
```

Comment: you forgot `where HS_PartList.PartName=HS.PartName` in the subquery

Comment: This gave only one result row with issueNo = 2 and not other parts with IssueNo = 1.

Comment: @SujaShyam that's what u asked with latest issueNo or maximum issueno